# For loop Selenium - Incomplete Task

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am performing an automation bot, capable of sharing post. However, when it comes to performing the task more than 3 times, I get an error and program stops working. I am not sure why my code is able to perform the task 3 times and then stops.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ECDS
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.poshmark.com") #Open webpage
Log_Field=(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Log in')]")
Email= (By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Username or Email']")
Pass= (By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Password']")
Second_Log= (By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn--primary']")
SF = (By.XPATH, "//img[@class='user-image user-image--s']")
MyCloset = (By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'My Closet')]")


WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(Log_Field)).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(Email)).send_keys("xx@xx.com")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Password']").send_keys("xxx")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn blue btn-primary']").click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(SF)).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(MyCloset)).click()

for i in range(100):
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.END)#Use send_keys(Keys.HOME)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[6]//div[1]//div[2]//div[3]//i[1]").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='share-wrapper-container']").click()
    driver.refresh()
time.sleep(20)
```

The error that I am getting is the following:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Bot_Poshmark.py", line 27, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[6]//div[1]//div[2]//div[3]//i[1]").click()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <i class="icon share-gray-large"></i> is not clickable at point (870, 163). Other element would receive the click: <div class="tile col-x12 col-l6 col-s8 p--2">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)
```

Any ideas why my code is only working not more than 3 times?
Thank you

Comment: Can you try to log in the element for JavaScript version I would have assigned `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[6]//div[1]//div[2]//div[3]//i[1]")` to a variable and logged not sure how it works with python

Comment: @BlackMamba I am not entirely understanding your comment. Would mind given me a little bit more of an explanation/clarification.  Thank you

Comment: Here's a link if it helps https://www.edureka.co/community/47955/selenium-exception-element-clickable-element-receive-click

Comment: @BlackMamba if I am properly understanding, here is the change I made `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH,  "//div[6]//div[1]//div[2]//div[3]//i[1]")).click()` the problem with that know is the following `TypeError: _init_() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem several times while testing my selenium web automation. As the exception tells, this object is not clickable. That means you have to dive deeper into the HTML tree to find an element that is always clickable. If you hover over the HTML-lines Chrome shows you the according piece of website.
However, if this is not possible, try to let your code `sleep()` for a bit :-)
You could do that for a certain amount of time

Or you use `WebDriverWait()` as in the comments described:
`WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,  "your XPATH"))).click()`
(You missed one `()`, this should remove your error: Without: Argument 1 = `self` [Keep that in mind with Python!!], Argument 2 = `By.XPATH` and 3 = `"the xpath"`. With the `()`, Argument 2 and 3 are together)

`WebDriverWait()` requires a `timeout` parameter because `selenium` does not know whether the element exists or not. But you could easily create your own `waiting-method`. **Pay attention:** you have to know that the element exists or you will end up with an infinite loop.

Here's the code:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def wait_for(driver, method):
    """Calls the method provided with the driver"""
    while True:
        try:
            element = method(driver)
            if element:
                return element
        except:
            pass
        sleep(0.5)
```

It tries to find the element and when it's found, it returns it.
You can use it like so:

```
el = wait_for(driver, EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,  "//input[@class='13e44'")))
el.click()
```

*Disclaimer:* This code is not fully my creation. I adapted the selenium source-code so it fits our needs :)

Comment: thank you for your response. As suggested I have added the `time.sleep(20)` to my code. However, that did not fix the problem, instead (and I am sure that this addition is not related to the issue) my code is only ruining one time. I have updated the error that I get in my original post, but it looks to me that is the same error message.

Comment: @Perro Have you checked my other suggestions?

Comment: Yes, I tried the `WebDriverWait()` option, however the error that I get now is `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Bot_Poshmark.py", line 27, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By. XPATH, "//div[6]//div[1]//div[2]//div[3]//i[1]"))).click()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`

Comment: @Perro Okay. As it is a timout exception, try to increase your maximum waiting time, which is set here to `20` seconds. You can either try `WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By. XPATH, "//div[6]//div[1]//div[2]//div[3]//i[1]"))).click()` or you can try `WebDriverWait(driver, NONE).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By. XPATH, "//div[6]//div[1]//div[2]//div[3]//i[1]"))).click()`. Please let me know if it works for you. I can then update my answer :) (If the first one doesn't work try the second one)

Comment: Once again thank you for your response. Unfortunately, with both of your suggestion I am still getting error messages. For the fist suggestion, `WebDriverWait (driver, 60)` I get the same error as before. For the second suggestion. `WebDriverWait (driver, NONE)` the error that I get is that `NONE` is not defined.

Comment: Well I just reviewed the source-code: You have to set a timeout. That's because selenium never knows wether this element really exists or not. So you have again two options: No. 1: You can do your automation manually and messure the time. Add 20 seconds and you have your timeout or No.2: You write your own waiting method (I will adapt my solution)

Comment: Thank you for your input and comments. As suggested, I have added a series of `time.sleep(20)` in my code and so far it has been working.

Comment: Great! Have a nice day :)